# AC contactor 1 pole or 2?

Tags: electrical, hvac

I wanted to title this: Outside unit running, but thermostat is off but I'm 99% sure its the contactor unless someone here says otherwise.

Thus my real question: which contactor should I buy? I typed in the part no. on Amazon but I'm experiencing death by choices. No where on my current contactor can I find the words 1 pole or the amperage. The variety of contactor choices I have are making me nervous. Heres the pic of my current one 
[image]

One last question, does manufacturer matter? Do I buy Siemens only?

Everything works fine by the way the fan just runs non-stop. Just fyi I've replaced the capacitor and a fuse on the control board this week.

Comment: That looks to me like it is a 1-pole contactor.  Is your unit at 240 V or 120 V?  I am pretty sure my 240 V condensing unit has a 2-pole contactor

Comment: So the outside fan is running continuously. Is the compressor running continuously too? Is the larger refrigerant line always cold. Is the air coming out of the vents inside always colder than the room?

Comment: Does the contactor operate the inside fan, outside fan, or the A/C compressor?

Comment: Also, don't buy the junk on Amazon. 99% of it is the "Amazon Marketplace" flea market, which is straightlined from Chinese counterfeiters or the QA reject line of the legitimate parts. Do not buy electrical parts that say "Sold by some-name-here and fulfilled by Amazon" (under the Buy button), that is Amazon Marketplace.  Ditto eBay, ditto alibaba/aliexpress.  That's the reason you're experiencing death by choices, you are including that trash.

Comment: Is it possible that you switched L1 and L2 when you changed the capacitor? So the compressor works as before, but if the fan was supposed to be on L1 it is now on L2 to neutral and running continuously. This is just a though and may not be possible.

Comment: @JimStewart Have you ever seen an outside air conditioning unit that has neutral?

Comment: No, but my experience is limited and I wouldn't remember. So this is not likely and presumably the contactor is stuck.

Comment: Is this a standard full sized split unit or a mini-split?

Comment: I hear you @harper but home depot didnt have any at all and i dont live near an electrical store... Any websites you would suggest ?

Comment: Sorry @jim what does that mean: split unit?

Comment: @jim Compressor is not running continuously, pipe is cold and air coming out is freezing so everything is good but woke up at 4am this morning and heard the fan just spinning

Comment: @InstructionPointer 99% of Americans drive by 3 electrical supplies everyday on the way to work and don't even know they're there. If there is civilization there are electricians, *and they have to get supplies somewhere*.  Nonetheless, that relay is more of an HVAC part, so heating/air conditioning supply houses are a better bet.  If you must mail order, Grainger and Galco are likely to have quality stock, and things **shipped from and sold by Amazon.com** are likely to be quality and legal to sell here.

Comment: If the compressor is *not* running continuously, but the condensing unit  fan is running continuously, then something strange is going on. The contactor is *not* stuck on if the compressor is cycling on and off. When you say the "compressor" you don't mean the inside air handler blower, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condensing unit fan is 120 V (L2 to neutral), then the fan would run continuously. But unless someone changed wires in the unit it should be connected to L1. You may be able to unstick the contactor  by tapping on it with a (non conducting) rod or other object.

If the current contactor is original, you should be able to get a correct replacement by cross referencing the Siemens number.

The info on the sticker "CONT1P025024V" presumably means 1-pole ("1P").

**EDIT** When you changed the capacitor did you possibly switch L1 and L2? The contactor may be OK.

Comment: I have never touch the contactor and when I replaced capacitor I hooked up the wires exactly as they were. I'll try taping it...

Comment: You are going to waste money and time by concluding without proper testing that the contactor is at fault.

Comment: Thank you Jim! You were right I would have wasted my money and time, come to find out I wired the ac wrong to the control board. I did red wire to R so it was getting constant power! Instead that red wire need to go to Y alongside a yellow Rosenthal goes to the thermostat so hopefully my ignorance is understandable... Thank you again and you saved me from a pointless purchase!

Answer (score 4):

The L1 and L2 designates the two feeds. The contactor is a one pole contactor with a shunt.  The voltage rating is 277volts.  The FLA designates full load amps, 25 Amps, which is the max rating for the contactor with inductive load.  The LRA designates locked rotor amps, 150 amps, which is the max rating for motor startup, and the res amps, 35amps, is the max amp rating for resistive load like lighting. The coil voltage is 24v and is fed from a transformer in the air handler. Your compressor would be considered inductive load.

You don't have to go with Siemens but get a good one... remember, you get what you pay for.

Also, your fan in the compressor, should not be running all the time, only when the compressor is running. Good luck.

Comment: OK I see the L1 and L2 connections but *it looks to me* like the L2 is just straight through which I would think would be called a one pole contactor. If both the compressor and the condensing fan are both 240 V, then there would be no need to interrupt both L1 and L2 to shut them off. There is presumably a 2-pole switch on the wall next to the unit to disconnect both L1 and  L2 to allow safe work on the unit.

Comment: See the info on the sticker "CONT1P025024V". Presumably the "1P" means 1-pole.

Comment: I see contactors that say "30 amp" and "40 amp" but not 35? Should i round up

Comment: The 35 amp is for resistive load..... 25  fla is what you're looking for. If it's not available you can go with a 30 fla.  Your compressor should have #10 awg cu wiring.